# VBA Controle de horas/funcionários

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Estou há dias tentando aprender os comandos em VBA para automatizar uma planilha de controle de horas de funcionários de uma empresa.

Tenho uma *sheet* com os nomes dos colaboradores e um calendário da seguinte forma:

```
                        horas   Local   Projeto horas   Local   Projeto ....
 COLABORADOR    FUNÇÃO  8-Mar   8-Mar   8-Mar   9-Mar   9-Mar   9-Mar
  felipe       exemplo  9:04    
    joão       exemplo
```

E outra *sheet* onde carrego o banco de horas que puxo do sistema com a seguinte forma.

Mostra o dia com horario de entrada e de saida.

```
felipe  8-Mar   7:50
felipe  8-Mar   16:54
joão    8-Mar   7:43
joão    8-Mar   17:00
...
```

Preciso comparar o nome do colaborador e alocar as horas trabalhadas no dia. O local e projeto serão carregados por outro meio.

Answer (score 1):

**Segue código que pode ser usado como base:**

```
   Sub teste()
        'Linha/Coluna BASE
        Dim linPlan1 As Integer
        Dim colPlan1 As Integer
        colPlan1 = 1
        linPlan1 = 4

        'FUNCIONARIO
        Dim nomeFunc As String

        Do While Plan1.Cells(linPlan1, colPlan1) <> ""

            nomeFunc = Plan1.Cells(linPlan1, colPlan1)
            hrInicio = Plan1.Cells(linPlan1, colPlan1 + 2)
            hrFim = Plan1.Cells(linPlan1 + 1, colPlan1 + 2)

            horasTrabalhadas = DateDiff("n", hrInicio, hrFim) / (24 * 60)
            'Plan1.Cells(4, 4) = horasTrabalhadas

            'PROCURA NOME FUNCIONARIO NA PLANILHA2
            Dim linPlan2 As Integer, colPlan2 As Integer
            colPlan2 = 1
            linPlan2 = 4
            Do While Plan2.Cells(linPlan2, colPlan2) <> ""
                If nomeFunc = Plan2.Cells(linPlan2, colPlan2) Then
                    Plan2.Cells(linPlan2, colPlan2 + 2) = horasTrabalhadas
                    Exit Do
                End If
                linPlan2 = linPlan2 + 1
            Loop

            linPlan1 = linPlan1 + 2 'pula para proximo nome planilha1
        Loop
    End Sub
```

**PLANILHA E RESULTADO:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Os campos "hora" devem estar no formato personalizado: Hora

Answer (score 1):

Isso também é possível utilizando [fórmulas matriciais](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Diretrizes-e-exemplos-de-f%C3%B3rmulas-de-matriz-3be0c791-3f89-4644-a062-8e6e9ecee523?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR), veja abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fórmula:
=MÁXIMO(SE(Plan2!$A$2:$A$100=Plan1!$A3;SE(Plan2!$B$2:$B$100=Plan1!C$2;Plan2!$C$2:$C$100))) - MÍNIMO(SE(Plan2!$A$2:$A$100=Plan1!$A3;SE(Plan2!$B$2:$B$100=Plan1!C$2;Plan2!$C$2:$C$100)))

Após terminar a fórmula, pressione Ctrl+Shift+Enter para determinar que é uma fórmula matricial.